# Facing assertion error when trying to add row inside a column

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a login page which looks like this

[image]

But whenever I try to add row which has another column iside it for textinput field and text It shows assertion error. I also tried removing sized box before text row still it is showing the same error
My flutter code:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: color,
     body: SafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,

            ),
            Text('Life Drop',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.white)),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,

            ),
           Text("your blood can save lives",
                 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white)),
          
          SizedBox(
            height:20.0
          ),

          Row(
            children: [
              Column(children: [
                Text('Login'),
                TextFormField(
                 controller: emailController,
                 decoration: const InputDecoration(
                   border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                   labelText: 'Email',
                 ),
               ),
               SizedBox(width: 20),
              ],)
            ],
          )

          
          
       
          ],
        ),
     ),

      )
       
   )
  );
   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

edit your row like below code:

```
            Expanded(
            child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Column(
              children: [
                const Text('Login'),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Email',
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 20),
              ],
            )),
          ],
        ))
```